# Paypal Plus getting error ""purchase_units[0]" - Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified)."

Tags: php, paypal, magento2, payment, paypal-plus

Hello I am working in magento 2. I have installed paypal plus payment.

https://marketplace.magento.com/iwaysgmbh-module-pay-pal-plus.html

All is working if I select country "Germany" in shipping address. I have configured in back-end and select "Allow All Country" in Payment from Applicable Countries.

But if I select other countries I am getting following error.

> Your address is invalid. Please check following errors: Field:
>   "purchase_units[0]" - Item amount must add up to specified amount
>   subtotal (or total if amount details not specified).

I have checked many links but nothing helped.

**Note :**

If I refreshed the page after getting this error then by click on place order it will work and redirect me to sandbox.

This is common issue as I found that others have same issue in different framework.

So please help me if anyone resolved the issue.